# how to execute mongodb run command in mule ?

Tags: mongodb, mule

I am trying this command in mongodb :

```
db.runCommand ( { distinct: "user", key: "city" } )
```

and got proper data.

I want to pass this command in mule. I am trying this in my mule flow:

```
<mongo:execute-command config-ref="Mongo_DB_Go"   doc:name="Mongo DB"  database="test" username="${db.user}" commandName="distinct" commandValue='{distinct : &quot;user&quot;, key : &quot;city&quot; }'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mongo:execute-command config-ref="Mongo_DB" commandName="eval" commandValue="db.runCommand({distinct: &quot;user&quot;, key: &quot;city&quot;})" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
```

It may be over-engineering but is the fastest solution I’ve got.

Comment: Greate Andra.ioana.  Perfect, it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That connector's documentation and example is a bit lacking, here's how it should be:

```
    <mongo:execute-command config-ref="Mongo_DB" commandName="distinctCommand" doc:name="Mongo DB" commandValue="function(){db.runCommand ( { distinct: &quot;user&quot;, key: &quot;city&quot; } )}"/>
```

Comment: I try your code and got this error  :  { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "no such command: 'distinctCommand', bad cmd: '{ distinctCommand: \"function(){db.runCommand({distinct:quot;user;quot;,key:quot;city;})}\" }'" , "code" : 59}